# Prevent writing a NULL or blank to field

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, constraints

I've done a lot of searching and testing, but I can't seem to find an example of this, or get any of my tests to work.

I have tables with many fields where they start as NULL (meaning the data is not known), and when they get data that data is never an empty string. Some of the update scripts that go over and over updating data to reflect a snapshot are quite convoluted and sometimes overwrite values with NULLs or blank values. The scripts are beyond our ability to really fix right now, so I want to take another tack, and prevent updates to fields with a NULL or blank when there is already data there.

Comment: Set an trigger to check if the value is updating to a null or a blank string and stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this sort of thing before using MySQL, but never with SQL Server, so my syntax may be slightly off. The basic gist is that you set a trigger on the table, and after an update occurs it runs an UPDATE-JOIN on all of the deleted rows (an update involves both a DELETE and an INSERT). The `deleted` table is a special object related to the trigger that we can use to obtain the old value. If the old value in `nullColumn` was `NULL`, the trigger sets the new value to `NULL` as well discarding any changes that might have been made.

```
CREATE TRIGGER nullKeep
  ON nullTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE a
    SET 
        nullColumn1 = CASE WHEN b.nullColumn1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE a.nullColumn1 END
      , nullColumn2 = CASE WHEN b.nullColumn2 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE a.nullColumn2 END
      , nullColumn3 = CASE WHEN b.nullColumn3 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE a.nullColumn3 END
    /* ...repeat for as many columns as you need... */
    FROM 
        nullTable a
    INNER JOIN 
        deleted b
        ON  a.ID = b.ID
  END
GO
```

Comment: How about for -every- column of a table? (There can be more than a few dozen)

Comment: See the updated answer for a solution that can be used on multiple columns.